# jquery $each on Json data undefined

Tags: javascript, c#

There is a lot of question regarding this topic, but I can't find the answer, nothing that I have read worked for me.

This is my call in Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "filter.aspx/filter",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data:"{'id':"+ id +" }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        console.log(data);
                        if (!jQuery.isArray(data)) data = [data];
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) { 
                            console.log(item.Name);
                            $("#customer_car_model").append( 
                                $("<option></option>") 
                                    .text(item.Name)
                                    .val(item.Oid)
                            );
                        });

                    }

                });
```

And my CodeBehind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string filter(string id)
    {

       //..Db Code
       //Save the items in a list object that has Name and Oid

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rp);
    }
```

The thing is when I print the data before the $.each method, it gave me this:

```
Object {d: "[{"Oid":"316","Name":"Acadia"},{"Oid":"317","Nam…Name":"Yukon"},{"Oid":"854","Name":"DENALI"}]"}
```

But When I print it after the $.each method using item.Name, gave me Undefined, I also tried with item["Name"] and data[index].Name and nothing, also undefined.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the data returned from the AJAX call?

Comment: @Satpal when I try data=data.d; and then iterate it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: What is  `...` in `"Nam…Name":"Yukon"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your object a bit to look like this:

```
var data = {d: '[{"Oid":"316","Name":"Acadia"},{"Oid":"317","Name":"Yukon"},{"Oid":"854","Name":"DENALI"}]'};
```

Now you need to set data like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data[0].d);
```

This should be done before `$.each(data, function (index, item) {`.
so that it gives a length of 3.

The way you were doing was making it an array of one element of object.
Doing above will give you the required array to loop.